# How to fix STATUS_BREAKPOINT error when going to location component?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a STATUS_BREAKPOINT error in my application, never had this error before. I checked on different versions of Google Chrome, version 114 has this error, but not on the old 112, how to fix this error? Here is my component code:

```
import {BaseDictionaryCardComponent} from "../../../../../infrastructure/sharedMembers/baseClasses/component/base-list-card-component/base-dictionary-card.component";
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {AfterViewInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Input} from "@angular/core";
import {ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";
import {LocationCardViewModel} from "./location-card.viewmodel";
import {NgSelectEmployeeSearchComponent} from "../../../../../infrastructure/global/components/wrappers/ng-select/ng-select-employee-search.component";
import {nameof} from '../../../../../infrastructure/sharedMembers/functions/nameof';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import {MonthYearCellEditorComponent} from '../../../../../infrastructure/global/components/wrappers/ag-grid/month-year-cell-editor.component';
import {CostTextRendererComponent} from '../../../../../infrastructure/global/components/wrappers/float-input/cost-text-renderer.component';
import {FloatCellEditorComponent} from '../../../../../infrastructure/global/components/wrappers/ag-grid/float-cell-editor.component';
import {AgGridEvent, ColumnApi, GridApi, GridOptions} from 'ag-grid-community';
import {LocationFactor} from "../../../../models/location-factor/location-factor";
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
    selector: "location-card",
    templateUrl: "location-card.component.html"
})
export class LocationCardComponent extends BaseDictionaryCardComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input()
    locationCardVm: LocationCardViewModel;

    @Input()
    isShowAllFilters: boolean;

    /** Selected tab index */
    public selectedTab: number = 0;

    /** Tab Visibility */
    public isTabsVisible: boolean;

    factorsGridApi: GridApi;
    factorsGridColumnApi: ColumnApi;

    @ViewChild("location")
    cardForm: NgForm;

    @ViewChild("employeeSelect")
    employeeSelect: NgSelectEmployeeSearchComponent;

    /** The name of this component for personalization.*/
    componentType = 'locationCard';
    /** Grid initialization and readiness indicator.*/
    gridInitFinishSubject: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    gridPersonalizationSettingsSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.isTabsVisible = this.translate.instant('EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.IS_SHOW_INDICATORS') === 'true';
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.locationCardVm.formObject = this.cardForm;
        this.locationCardVm.employeeSelect = this.employeeSelect;
        this.locationCardVm.component = this;
        // Branch must be set by default
        this.locationCardVm.employeeSelect.select.businessUnit = this.locationCardVm._userBusinessUnit;
    }

    /** Tab click handler */
    tabSelected(number: number) {
        this.selectedTab = number;
    }

    /** Add indicator */
    addFactor() {
        let factor = new LocationFactor();
        factor.locationId = this.locationCardVm.entity.id;
        this.locationCardVm.factors = [...this.locationCardVm.factors, factor];
        this.sortTable();
    }

    /** Delete indicator */
    removeIndicator() {
        let selectedRows = this.factorsGridApi.getSelectedRows();

        if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length) {
            selectedRows.forEach(x => {
                let index = this.locationCardVm.factors.indexOf(x);
                if (index >= 0) {
                    this.locationCardVm.factors.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
        }
        this.sortTable();
        this.factorsGridApi.setRowData(this.locationCardVm.factors);
    }

    /** Sort indicators */
    sortTable() {
        this.locationCardVm.factors = this.locationCardVm.factors
            .sort((a, b) => (a.date < b.date) ? -1 : (a.date > b.date) ? 1 : 0);
        this.locationCardVm.isChanged = true;
    }

    indicatorsGridOptions: GridOptions = {
        context: {
            componentParent: this
        },
        defaultColDef: {
            resizable: true,
            suppressMenu: true,
            autoHeight: true,
            cellClass: "cell-wrap-text",
            editable: true,
            headerClass: params => {
                // Columns that can be edited in edit modes are highlighted.
                const columnIsEditable = !this.disabled && params && params.colDef
                    && this.columnIsEditable(params.colDef.colId);
                if (columnIsEditable) {
                    return "header-primary-bg";
                }
            }
        },
        domLayout: "autoHeight",
        rowHeight: 35,
        headerHeight: 35,
        rowBuffer: 999,
        suppressContextMenu: true,
        suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true,
        suppressColumnMoveAnimation: true,
        suppressRowClickSelection: true,
        suppressMultiSort: true,
        suppressPropertyNamesCheck: true,
        rowSelection: "multiple"
    };

    private readonly _nonEditableColumnIds: string[] = [
        "checkbox",
        "workedHours",
        "internalEmployeesWorkedHours",
        "externalEmployeesWorkedHours"
    ];

    factorsColumnDefs: any[] = [
        {
            checkboxSelection: () => !this.disabled,
            headerCheckboxSelection: () => !this.disabled,
            colId: "checkbox",
            width: 40,
            suppressSizeToFit: true,
            sortable: false,
            resizable: false,
        },
        {
            headerName: this.translate.instant("EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.PERIOD"),
            headerTooltip: this.translate.instant("EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.PERIOD"),
            children: [
                {
                    headerName: "",
                    headerTooltip: "",
                    field: nameof<LocationFactor>("date"),
                    fitWidth: 50,
                    cellRenderer: params => {
                        if (params && params.value) {
                            let periods = this.locationCardVm.factors.filter(f => f.date ? f.date.getFullYear() == params.value.getFullYear()
                                && f.date.getMonth() == params.value.getMonth() : false);
                            if (periods && periods.length > 1) {
                                params.value = null;
                                this.locationCardVm.factors[params.rowIndex].date = null;
                                this.locationCardVm.factors[params.rowIndex].wasValidated = false;
                            }
                        }
                        return `<span>${params && params.value ? moment(params.value).format("MM.YYYY") : "__.____"}</span>`;
                    },
                    cellEditorFramework: MonthYearCellEditorComponent,
                    cellEditorParams: {
                        onChanged: (newValue: Date, rowIndex: number) => {
                            this.locationCardVm.factors[rowIndex].date = newValue;
                            this.locationCardVm.factors[rowIndex].wasValidated = false;
                            this.locationCardVm.isChanged = true;
                        },
                        required: true,
                        // function to get blocked selected dates, remove the empty value
                        getDisabledDates: () => this.locationCardVm.factors.map(factor => factor.date).filter(date => !!date),
                        readonlyInput: true,
                    },
                    cellClassRules: {
                        "required-cell": (params) => {
                            return !params.data || (params.data.wasValidated && !params.data.date);
                        }
                    }
                }]
        },
        {
            colId: "workedHours",
            headerName: this.translate.instant("EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.CONTINUITY_HOUR_WORKS"),
            headerTooltip: this.translate.instant("EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.CONTINUITY_HOUR_WORKS"),
            children: [
                {
                    colId: "internalEmployeesWorkedHours",
                    headerName: this.translate.instant("EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.EMPLOYEES"),
                    headerTooltip: this.translate.instant("EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.EMPLOYEES"),
                    field: nameof<LocationFactor>("internalEmployeesWorkedHours"),
                    cellRendererFramework: CostTextRendererComponent,
                    cellRendererParams: {
                        fractionDigits: 2
                    },
                    editable: false,
                    fitWidth: 50
                },
                {
                    colId: "externalEmployeesWorkedHours",
                    headerName: this.translate.instant("EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.SUBPO"),
                    headerTooltip: this.translate.instant("EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.SUBPO"),
                    field: nameof<LocationFactor>("externalEmployeesWorkedHours"),
                    cellRendererFramework: CostTextRendererComponent,
                    cellRendererParams: {
                        fractionDigits: 2
                    },
                    editable: false,
                    fitWidth: 50
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            headerName: this.translate.instant("EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.LTIFR"),
            headerTooltip: this.translate.instant("EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.LTIFR"),
            children: [
                {
                    headerName: "",
                    headerTooltip: "",
                    field: nameof<LocationFactor>("targetLTIFR"),
                    cellRendererFramework: CostTextRendererComponent,
                    cellRendererParams: {
                        fractionDigits: 2
                    },
                    cellEditorFramework: FloatCellEditorComponent,
                    cellEditorParams: {
                        onChanged: (newValue: number, rowIndex: number) => {
                            this.locationCardVm.factors[rowIndex].targetLTIFR = newValue;
                            this.locationCardVm.isChanged = true;
                        },
                        required: true,
                        significantLength: 2,
                    },
                    cellClassRules: {
                        "required-cell": (params) => {
                            return !params.data || (params.data.wasValidated && params.data.targetLTIFR == null);
                        }
                    },
                    fitWidth: 50
                }
            ]
        }
    ];


    // Table readiness event handler for displaying agenda items
    onFactorsGridReady(gridReadyEvent: AgGridEvent) {
        this.factorsGridApi = gridReadyEvent.api;
        this.factorsGridColumnApi = gridReadyEvent.columnApi;
        this.factorsGridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
        this.setTableEditable();
        this.onGridInitFinished();
    }

    onGridInitFinished() {
        this.gridInitFinishSubject.next(true);
    }

    onGridSizeChanged() {
        if (this.factorsGridApi) {
            this.factorsGridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
            this.factorsGridApi.resetRowHeights();
        }
    }

    /** Table editability*/
    private setTableEditable() {
        if (!this.factorsColumnDefs || !this.factorsGridApi) return;

        // Top-level columns that can be edited in edit modes are highlighted.
        this.factorsColumnDefs
            .forEach(col => {
                col.editable = this.columnIsEditable(col.colId);
                col.headerClass = col.editable ? "header-primary-bg" : null;
        });
        this.factorsGridApi.setColumnDefs(this.factorsColumnDefs);
        this.factorsGridApi.refreshCells({force: true});
    }

    private columnIsEditable(colId: string) {
        return this._nonEditableColumnIds.indexOf(colId) < 0 && !this.disabled;
    }

    /** Delete button activity */
    get isRemoveActive(): boolean {
        let selectedRows = this.factorsGridApi ? this.factorsGridApi.getSelectedRows() : [];
        return this.locationCardVm.factors && this.locationCardVm.factors.length > 0 && selectedRows && selectedRows.length > 0;
    }

    /** Table update */
    refreshFactorsCells() {
        if (this.factorsGridApi) {
            this.factorsGridApi.refreshCells();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!--Location-->
<form id="location" #location="ngForm" name="location">

    <tabset *ngIf="isTabsVisible">

        <!-- Basic data -->
        <tab heading="{{'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.MAIN_INFORMATION' | translate}}"
             ngModelGroup="firstTab"
             #firstTabGroup="ngModelGroup"
             [attr.data-id]="'main_information_tab'"
             [attr.descr]="'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.MAIN_INFORMATION'|translate"
             [customClass]="firstTabGroup && firstTabGroup.invalid ? 'invalid-tab': ''"
             (select)="tabSelected(0)"
             [active]="selectedTab == 0">

            <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateMainInformation"></ng-template>
        </tab>

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <tab heading="{{'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.INDICATORS' | translate}}"
             [attr.data-id]="'indicators_tab'"
             [attr.descr]="'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.INDICATORS'|translate"
             [customClass]="!locationCardVm.factorsValid ? 'invalid-tab': ''"
             (select)="tabSelected(1)"
             [active]="selectedTab == 1">

            <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-1 pt-3">
                <label class="gray-label mr-3 align-self-center">{{'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.PERIOD'|translate}}</label>

                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-circle"
                        type="button"
                        [attr.data-id]="'add_period'"
                        [attr.descr]="'EMPLOYEES.BUSINESS_UNIT.FACTORS_TAB.ADD_BTN_HINT'|translate"
                        title="{{'EMPLOYEES.BUSINESS_UNIT.FACTORS_TAB.ADD_BTN_HINT'|translate}}"
                        (click)="addFactor()">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>

                <button [attr.data-id]="'remove-btn'"
                        [attr.descr]="'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.REMOVE_PERIOD'|translate"
                        class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-circle ml-auto"
                        type="button"
                        title="{{'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.REMOVE_PERIOD'|translate}}"
                        (click)="removeIndicator()"
                        [disabled]="!isRemoveActive">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div *ngIf="!locationCardVm.factors || locationCardVm.factors && locationCardVm.factors.length === 0"
                 class="text-secondary bg-light text-center p-1 mt-1 mb-3">
                {{'COMMON.NODATA'|translate}}
            </div>

            <ag-grid-angular [attr.data-id]="'indicators_table'"
                             *ngIf="selectedTab == 1 && locationCardVm.factors && locationCardVm.factors.length > 0"
                             class="ag-theme-balham h-100 w-100"
                             [rowData]="locationCardVm.factors"
                             [columnDefs]="factorsColumnDefs"
                             [gridOptions]="indicatorsGridOptions"
                             (gridReady)="onFactorsGridReady($event)"
                             agGridWithHotKeys
                             (gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged()"
                             ag-grid-scale-patch
                             [personalization]="componentType"
                             [isRegistryTable]="false"
                             [gridReadySubject]="gridInitFinishSubject"
                             (onPersonalizationInit)="this.gridPersonalizationSettingsSubject.next(true)">
            </ag-grid-angular>

        </tab>
    </tabset>

    <!-- Inserted if here if tabs are not needed -->
    <ng-template *ngIf="!isTabsVisible" [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateMainInformation"></ng-template>

    <ng-template #templateMainInformation>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'pt-3': isTabsVisible}">
            <label class="gray-label">{{'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.NAME'|translate}}</label>
            <input class="form-control"
                   required
                   name="name"
                   [attr.data-id]="'name'"
                   [attr.descr]="'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.NAME'|translate"
                   [(ngModel)]="locationCardVm.entity.name" #name="ngModel"
                   maxlength="100">
            <div class="invalid-feedback d-block"
                 *ngIf="name && name.errors && name.errors.notunique  && name.pristine">
                {{'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_INVALID'|translate}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Managers-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="gray-label">{{'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.MANAGERS'|translate}}</label>
            <div>
                <ng-select-employee-search #employeeSelect [(ngModel)]="locationCardVm.entity.internalEmployees"
                                           name="managers"
                                           [attr.data-id]="'managers'"
                                           [attr.descr]="'EMPLOYEES.LOCATIONS.MANAGERS'|translate"
                                           [multiple]="true"
                                           [required]="false"
                                           [filterPlacement]="'bottom'"
                                           [isShowAllFilters]="isShowAllFilters"
                                           [forceBusinessUnitShow]="true"
                                           [disabled]="viewBrowseMode==viewStateEnum.Browse">
                </ng-select-employee-search>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</form>
```

I tried to gradually remove different components from this one, but it did not help.
This page works in mozilla and in chrome version 112, but not on 114, and it doesn’t work in the edge browser either.
At the time of the error, I don't get errors in the developer console and network

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire error as text. Also, please include some evidence of research. [A quick search on a popular search engine brings back many, many results](https://www.google.com/search?q=STATUS_BREAKPOINT)

Comment: I found a solution: I deleted the id and name from the form, it worked for me, I still don’t understand how it is related to the new version.